# problem to retrieve all values of vehicles in DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I need help for collecting all data from DBpedia about vehicle inside Infobox.
My challenge is I get the same Vehicle (e.g I get only Tesla data but not other cars) data every time, but I want to collect additional data.

I started with this code:

```sql
SELECT distinct ?model ?manufacturer_name WHERE { 
?x dbo:manufacturer/dbo:wikiPageRedirects? ?manufacturer .
?x foaf:name ?model .
?manufacturer dbo:industry <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Automotive_industry> .
?manufacturer foaf:name ?manufacturer_name 
} order by ?manufacturer_name ?model
```

Comment: that cannot be, your query returns plenty of results if your run it here: https://dbpedia.org/sparql - check your source code if your running the query via some unknown API in an unknown programming language

Comment: sorry I only have the car and manufacturer, but I need all fields for all vehicles : Production,,Assembly,Designer,Class,Body style,Platform,Doors,Related,motor,Transmission,Electric,range,Wheelbase,LengthWidth,Height etc

Comment: then you can just add another triple pattern `?x ?p ?o` and select `?p` and `?o`